# Swift - How to change view programmatically after validating from outside server

Tags: ios, swift, validation, authentication, server

I have a login view page that should transition to a tab view controller once the login has been verified. However, I get an error instantiating the view within the session.dataTask

```
[24249:381955] [Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected and insidious behavior.
```

Which results in a

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How can I validate the user and bring him to the main page after validating from a server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you shouldn't perform that operation on a background thread.

Move your instantiation code into main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
// view instantition here.
}
```

Comment: @ImranQ Anytime you do something that alters the view, do it on the main thread.

Comment: Do you know why that is? I was wondering what the key differences are between background threads and main threads